# How to simplify these dictionary comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

The code below is working and brings the results I want. However, there two sets of two dictionary comprehensions that I am not able to transform into two dictionary comprehensions. Is that possible?

```
dicTfAll={1:{'c1': ['aa','bb','cc']},
         2:{'c1': ['dd','ee','ff']}}


dicTf={1:{'c2': ['aax','bbx','cc']},
         2:{'c2': ['ddy','eey','ff']},
         3: {'c2': ['xx', '11']}}

allKeys=list(dicTfAll.keys())
dicTfAllP1={item[0]:item[1]  for item in dicTf.items() if item[0] not in allKeys}
dicTfAllP2={item[0]:dict(dicTfAll[item[0]],**item[1])  for item in dicTf.items() if item[0] in allKeys}
dicTfAllP=dicTfAllP1
dicTfAllP.update(dicTfAllP2)
# I use at this point dicTfAllP to do a lot of calculations. 
# dicTfAllP has the same form but very different values. 
allKeys=list(dicTfAllP.keys())
listOfCompanies=['c1','c2']
outputCompanies={}
for company in listOfCompanies:
    theKeys=[key for key in allKeys if company in dicTfAllP[key]]
    outputCompanies[company]={token:key  for key in theKeys for token in dicTfAllP[key][company]}
```

To be precise I would like to transform these lines below in one dictionary comprehension [it generates a nested dictionary, which is a merge of the above dictionaries]:

```
allKeys=list(dicTfAll.keys())
dicTfAllP1={item[0]:item[1]  for item in dicTf.items() if item[0] not in allKeys}
dicTfAllP2={item[0]:dict(dicTfAll[item[0]],**item[1])  for item in dicTf.items() if item[0] in allKeys}
```

Furthermore, I would like to transform these lines below in also one dictionary comprehension [it builds a nested dictionary that recovers the original dictionaries (before the merge)]:

```
outputCompanies={}
for company in listOfCompanies:
    theKeys=[key for key in allKeys if company in dicTfAllP[key]]
    outputCompanies[company]={token:key  for key in theKeys for token in dicTfAllP[key][company]}
```

I am particularly worried about the efficiency of the implementation. What can be done if I need to keep this kind of structure?
I do have to keep this structure because I have to do a lot of calculations between the two sets of dict comprehensions.

Comment: Why are you making a list of keys??

Answer (score 2):

Comprehensions are an amazing feature of python, but they're not always the best case. Rather than creating a ton of variables and mashing them together, it might be good to process them one at a time. I'm sure it's possible to squeeze more juice out of this code, but this should provide a nice balance of readability and processing power. I checked the output to make sure it matched the output of your code.

```
dicTfAll = {
    1: {'c1': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']},
    2: {'c1': ['dd', 'ee', 'ff']}
}

dicTf = {
    1: {'c2': ['aax', 'bbx', 'cc']},
    2: {'c2': ['ddy', 'eey', 'ff']},
    3: {'c2': ['xx', '11']}
}

outputCompanies = {}

for d in [dicTfAll, dicTf]:
    for idx, records in d.items():
        for company, items in records.items():

            if company not in outputCompanies.keys():
                outputCompanies[company] = {}

            for item in items:
                outputCompanies[company][item] = idx

print(outputCompanies)
# {
#     'c2': {'11': 3, 'ddy': 2, 'eey': 2, 'cc': 1, 'xx': 3, 'ff': 2, 'bbx': 1, 'aax': 1}, 
#     'c1': {'aa': 1, 'bb': 1, 'cc': 1, 'dd': 2, 'ee': 2, 'ff': 2}
# }
```

Since you're looking for more performant code, here's a comparison of runtimes using `%%timeit` in jupyter lab.

```
# My version
2.99 µs ± 30 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)


# Original Version
6.39 µs ± 25.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

I also tried a slightly more compact version of the code, but it ended up taking longer to run.

```
%%timeit
outputCompanies = defaultdict(dict)

for d in [dicTfAll, dicTf]:
    for idx, records in d.items():
        for company, items in records.items():
            outputCompanies[company].update({item: idx for item in items})

# 4.88 µs ± 22.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Another test which actually includes a comprehension:

```
%%timeit
outputCompanies = {}

for d in [dicTfAll, dicTf]:
    for idx, records in d.items():
        for company, items in records.items():

            if company not in outputCompanies.keys():
                outputCompanies[company] = {}

            outputCompanies[company].update({
                item: idx for item in items
            })
# 4.99 µs ± 23.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

As for some comments on your code, `dict.keys()` returns a `list` object, so there's no need to call `list(dict.keys())`. There is also no need to create the variable `allKeys` since you can call `dict.keys()` in your dictionary comprehensions. Companies are hard coded which is fine if this is a one off script, but not the best if you expect the dataset to expand over time. But if you wanted to hard code them, you could skip a variable declaration and just type `for company in ['c1','c2']:`. Next, you can save some more variables by creating `dicTfAllP` equal to the first comprehension and then updating it with the second. Put that all together and you'd get the following code. It is more readable and a bit easier to follow, but not much more performant.

```
%%timeit
dicTfAllP = {
    item[0]:item[1]
    for item 
    in dicTf.items()
    if item[0] not in dicTfAll.keys()
}

dicTfAllP.update({
    item[0]: dict(dicTfAll[item[0]], **item[1])
    for item 
    in dicTf.items() 
    if item[0] in dicTfAll.keys()
})

outputCompanies = {}
for company in ['c1','c2']:
    theKeys = [key for key in dicTfAllP.keys() if company in dicTfAllP[key]]
    outputCompanies[company] = {
        token:key
        for key in theKeys 
        for token in dicTfAllP[key][company]
    }
# 6.11 µs ± 58.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: **dict.keys() returns a list** Are you talking about python 3? `dict.keys()` returns a view object. And often it is unnecessary as iterating on the dict yields the keys. But if you need a separate iterable, yes make a list of the keys

Comment: +1: But, in fact, I cannot do both process together (I cannot run the two sets of dict comprehensions togeter). Thats the reason I considered each of dict comprenhension separated. There are lots of calculations between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can build dicTfAllP using this comprehension:

```
dicTfAllP = {k:{**dicTfAll.get(k,{}),**dicTf.get(k,{})} for k in set(dicTfAll).union(dicTf)}
```

For outputCompanies you would need the help of `groupby` from itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby
outputCompanies = {c:dict((k,v) for _,k,v in vs) for c,vs in groupby(sorted( (c,v,n) for n,cs in dicTfAllP.items() for c,vs in cs.items() for v in vs),key=lambda x:x[0])}
```

Since the above line is a bit convoluted, you could decompose it to keep things legible:

```
companyPairs    = ((c,v,n) for n,cs in dicTfAllP.items() for c,vs in cs.items() for v in vs)
groupedData     = groupby(sorted(companyPairs),key=lambda x:x[0])
outputCompanies = {c:dict((k,v) for _,k,v in vs) for c,vs in groupedData }
```

Inspecting the intermediate results will allow you to see what's going on.